# Setting group owner to another group does not supported by azure graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The reference target 'Group_d45c5707-c004-438e-9f69-526400b65cde' of type 'Group' is invalid for the 'owners' reference.

Comment: There isn't enough detail here, could you explain more about what you attempted to do and what results you were expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you cannot set a group owner to be a group.  If that's the case, then yes this is not currently supported (as per https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_owners this is only for users).  If you are asking for this as a new platform feature please file a request on uservoice here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Hope this helps,